# How to integrate FnordMetric in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to view the chart format using the dynamic data in rails applicaiton.

So i am trying to integrate the FnordMetric in my app

I have installed

```
gem 'fnordmetric'
```

and followed the steps described here http://railscasts.com/episodes/378-fnordmetric?view=asciicas

I can able to run file with ruby command and chart is displaying in localhost:4242

But i want to run FnordMetric using rails instead of running via ruby command and want to display my chart in rails application instead of different port such as localhost:4242

Can any one tried using it?

Answer (score 3):

You can look through [this article](http://fnordmetric.io/documentation/ui_index/).

But, briefly. I assume, that you have successfully completed steps from article, that you gave.

1. Add to your app/assets/javascripts folder fnordmetric-ui.js
2. Add to your app/assets/stylesheets folder fnordmetric-ui.css
3. Add to your view (let's say index.html)

In index.html:

```
<script>
  FnordMetric.setup({
    "address":   "localhost:4242",
    "namespace": "store"
  });
</script>


  <div
  data-fnordmetric="timeseries"
  data-gauges="product_views_per_second"
  data-since="-60m"
  data-until="now"
  data-autoupdate="1"
  ></div>
```

Documentation gives wrong url for downloading fnordmetric-ui.js and fnordmetric-ui.css files. I found them [here](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/fnordmetric/1.2.9/files/web/fnordmetric-ui.css).